# How would we write syntax for Oracle sql case expression

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to write Oracle sql case expression for the below condition, I have tried writing as mentioned below. It is working fine for me.

```
Case Expression
X0= Tenor applied
X1= Asset cost
X2=Loan amount applied 
X3= Computed_LTV =(X2/X1)*100
```

Conditions are as follows,

```
1.If X0>24 then W1=0 
2.If 19<=X0<=24 & X3 >56.181 then W1=8
3.If X0<19 then W1=18
4.If 19<=X0<=24 & X3<56.181 then W1=18 
5.Else 0
```

My code-

```
Case,
WHEN Tenor applied>24 THEN W1=0
WHEN Tenor applied BETWEEN 19 AND 24 AND SUM(Loan amount 
applied/ASSET CODE)*100 >56.181 THEN 8
WHEN Tenor applied<19 THEN 18
WHEN Tenor applied BETWEEN 19 AND 24 AND SUM(Loan amount 
applied/ASSET CODE)*100 <56.181 THEN 18
ELSE 0
```

Comment: Case [statement](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/CASE-statement.html#GUID-F4251A23-0284-4990-A156-00A92F83BC35) and [expression](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/CASE-Expressions.html#GUID-CA29B333-572B-4E1D-BA64-851FABDBAE96)

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
   w1 :=
      CASE
         WHEN x0 > 24
         THEN
            0
         WHEN     x0 BETWEEN 19 AND 24
              AND (x2 / x1) * 100 > 56.181      --> this is x3
         THEN
            8
         WHEN     x0 BETWEEN 19 AND 24
              AND (x2 / x1) * 100 < 56.181      --> this is x3
         THEN
            18
         ELSE
            0
      END;
```